How can I rotate a group of pyglet/arcade objects (either shapes or images)
It seems pyglet/arcade are not a good choice for writing advanced games (by that, I mean not Space Invaders, Pac Man or Mario alike games but games like Dune 2 The Battle for Arrakis, Tiberium Sun, Starcraft, etc.)
I want to know how to manipulate groups (rotate, scale, move).
Expected result:

The same question was already asked about pygame:
here:
